# Excel -> Need Cell Location reported from MATCH() to yield cell location elsewhere so I can AVG between two cells

Tags: excel-2016

Having a tough time explaining what I need. An example at the bottom.

I need to average between two points in a column that is constantly changing depending on the start split between different races. The start point is always at the same cell (LightBeam "S"), cell 502 (including row header) but the end point is always different (athletes go slower or faster).

I used MATCH() to get the endpoint location based on a tag point in another cell (LightBeam "1"), for example, cell 1010 is where the split ends.

How do I go from the cell reporting 1010 to give me the B1010, which is the column where the speed data is?

Because if I can get the cell to report "B502", another cell to report "B1010", I can average them.

If I copy another race and paste it in the end value will change, but I still want it to average the speed within the two markers LightBeam "S" and LightBeam "1" - reporting the AVG Speed correctly each time.

A      B           C         D
Time Speed(kph) LightBeam LBTime(S)
0.00  0.00          S         0.00
0.01  1.00
0.02  2.00
0.03  2.50
0.04  3.40          1        0.04

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Indirect function to get the value of a cell given its address

```
=INDIRECT("B" & {cell containing 1010})
```

Comment: This gives me the value of the cell B1010, which is "1.47" but I want it to report "B1010". Then I can use the formula =AVERAGE({B502}:{B1010}). Said another way, if it's reporting "B502" and "B1010" in cell F4 and F5 respectively I can then select those cells to =AVERAGE(cell location in F4:cell location in F5) which should average the values between B502 and B1010. Again, the later value changes depending on the split so one athlete can go 5.00seconds and thats cell B1010 where another can go 5.05 seconds and that would be cell B1015, hence why I need it to give the column and row number.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks!